# ReportViewer change language toolbars Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I need change language 
    `toolbars reportviewer.Buttons:Print,Find,Export`
 ...is possible?
I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement IReportViewerMessages. Is easy.

- Create a Class file in App_Code folder
- Put into a NameSpace (eg: MessagesRV)
- Create a class in this NameSpace (eg: ES) and add "implements Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportViewerMessages. Push Intro and Visual Studio creates all properties needes.
- Completes the properties with your own messages.

See a example in : http://toniogago.wordpress.com/2010/12/04/cambiar-idioma-control-reportviewer/

I try changing culture but no results.

I don't install language pack. I work at Spain at Region Galicia (Norwest) with a own language (not spanish --> Gallego) and i found more usefull creating a class.

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the language pack for the desired language. Language packs are [available here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C1DF3B07-09D7-48CB-BB63-DF6D3C2F8141). The ReportViewer should then appear in the language corresponding to the [CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28VS.80%29.aspx) set in your application. By default, the current culture should correspond to the one chosen in your Windows regional settings.

In other words, if your OS language is set to french, for example, and you have the french language pack installed, then the ReportViewer should be in french, unless you changed the CurrentCulture in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by creating a custom toolbar.
I beleive that the culture update needs to be applied to all client PCs, however, I may be wrong about this.